# Facebook unable to scrape website by domain name. Does work great with IP

Tags: facebook, nginx, dns, digital-ocean, http-response-codes

I'm trying to let Facebook scrape our newly launched website on a DigitalOcean server. When we do this by it's IP — 178.62.136.69 — this works great. However, if we use the domain name — www.stuvoplus.be — attached to that IP; we get the following error:

> Critical Errors That Must Be Fixed
>
> Bad Response Code URL returned a bad HTTP response code.

So, in some weird way Facebook accepts the direct IP but ignores the attached domain. We tried calling our provider for the domain name, yet they throw the ball directly back at us by saying they did what they needed to do: add the correct records so that the domain is pointed to the IP.

Is there anything we can do to make Facebook scrape our site correctly?

Thank you in advance,

Sem

[Response code 200 with IP Crawl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h07D6.png)

[Response code 404 with domain Crawl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmqT5.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook can't scrape meta data after I've moved Wordpress to new server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220600/facebook-cant-scrape-meta-data-after-ive-moved-wordpress-to-new-server)

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. Since the DNS records had both an ipv4 as an ipv6 address, Facebook's crawler took the ipv6 as default gateway. Our server didn't listen on ipv6 so Facebook couldn't access the server. We deleted the ipv6 record and after 1 hour everything worked like a charm.